# Deleting image after moving around in java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, paintcomponent

I am having trouble to deal with the deletion of images after moving it around [spaceship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfyDO.png)

First i have my MovingSprite class that makes the Board:

public class MovingSpriteEx extends JFrame {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public MovingSpriteEx() {
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    add(new Board());
    
    setTitle("Moving sprite");
    setSize(500,400);
    
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    System.out.println("calling");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        MovingSpriteEx ex = new MovingSpriteEx();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

}

My Board class is using a paintComponent to paint from a Spaceship class like this:

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Timer timer;
private Spaceship ship;
private final int DELAY = 10;
private boolean incrementX = true;
private boolean incrementY=true;

public Board() {
    
    initBoard();
    
}

private void initBoard() {//building the frame
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());//listens to the KeyAdapter that can read on the keyboards input
    setBackground(Color.black);
    setFocusable(true);
    
    ship = new Spaceship();
    timer = new Timer(DELAY,this);
    timer.start();
    
    
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    
        doDrawing(g);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    
    
    
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(ship.getImage(),ship.getX(), ship.getY(), this);
    
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    step();
}

private void step() {
    
    
    ship.move();
    
    
    repaint(ship.getX()-1,ship.getY()-1,ship.getWidth()+2,ship.getHeight()+2);
}


private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter{
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        ship.keyReleased(e);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        ship.keyPressed(e);
    }
}
```

}

and the Spaceship class:

public class Spaceship {

```
private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x = 40;
private int y = 60;
private int w;
private int h;
private Image image;

public Spaceship() {

    loadImage();
}

private void loadImage() {
    
    ImageIcon ii =  createImageIcon("../Images/spaceship.jpg","something");
    
    
    image = ii.getImage(); 
    
    
    w = ii.getIconWidth();
    h = ii.getIconHeight();
}

private ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path, String description) {
    java.net.URL imgURL = getClass().getResource(path);
    if (imgURL != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL, description);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
        return null;
    }
}

public void move() {
    
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public int getX() {
    
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    
    return y;
}

public int getWidth() {
    
    return w;
}

public int getHeight() {
    
    return h;
}    

public Image getImage() {
  
    return image;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        dx = -2;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        dx = 2;
        
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dy = -2;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dy = 2;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        dx = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dy = 0;
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    
}
```

}

hope someone can see what i am doing wrong

Rasmus

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. You can [edit] your question at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is drawing the ship image to your board (JPanel) every frame but not clearing the image that was drawn the frame before, JPanel won't do that for you.   Keep a copy of the co-ordinates you use when calling drawImage, then  clear that area next time around, for your plain background you can just use a fillRect.

For instance, as you are drawing over a plain black background, you could add something like the following to your Spaceship class and call it instead of calling drawImage in doDrawing.

```
private java.awt.Rectangle dirtyArea;
public void draw(java.awt.Graphics2D g2d, java.awt.image.ImageObserver observer) {
    if (dirtyArea != null) {
        g2d.setColor(java.awt.Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(dirtyArea.x, dirtyArea.y, dirtyArea.width, dirtyArea.height);
    }
    int shipX = getX();
    int shipY = getY();
    Image shipImage = getImage();
    g2d.drawImage(shipImage, shipX, shipY, observer);

    if (dirtyArea == null || dirtyArea.width == -1) {  // -1 check is there just in case the image wasn't loaded when this code ran before
        dirtyArea = new java.awt.Rectangle();
        dirtyArea.setSize(shipImage.getWidth(null), shipImage.getHeight(null)); // don't need observer as we're checking for -1 next time round
    }
    dirtyArea.setLocation(shipX, shipY);
}
```

Comment: Just to add, once you've got more than one sprite on screen at once, you'll be wanting to clear all the dirty areas before drawing the first sprite (so the fillRects don't obscure any of the sprites), the approach above is just the simplest example while you're only drawing a single ship, if you were carrying on with this approach you'd probably add a new method to Spaceship that just clears the dirty area (the part inside the != null block), doDrawing would then call the clear dirty area method for all sprites, followed by the draw method for all sprites.

Comment: *"Just to add,.."* best expressed as an [edit] to the answer.